# Readonly tag MVC depending of a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My model has an property whcih I assigned a ReadOnly tag. My intention is to set a propery to readonly true or false depending of a condition like

```
class Test {
  static bool test() { // It is my model
    // My logical response ...
    return true;
  }


  [ReadOnly(test)]
  datetime prop {get; set;}

}
```

using this model I get the error message:

```
Error   7 An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter
```

Could you, pleaee, get me an idea for this?

=====================================================================================

Solution like answer 3:

Inside Template:

cshtml:

```
    ...
    @if (Model.condition) {
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.prop)</td>
    } else {
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.prop)</td>
    }
    ...
```

It will be inside the template.

Inside Model in the copmnstructor I set the condition of the property condition:

```
class XX {
  public condition { get; set; } // not necessary readonly, I do the logical inside the template.
  public datetime prop {get; set; }

  public XX (bool _condition) {
     condition = _condition;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tell me please, how the property is being set in your case? By the MVC engine while modelbinding or manually?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use something other than described in the error message as the parameter for attributes.

It is a sad true, but still a true.

Only this:

```
[ReadOnly(5)]
[ReadOnly("string")] // Or other type (int/long/byte/etc..) which can be used with const keyword.
[ReadOnly(Enums.SomeValue)]
[ReadOnly(typeof(SomeType))]
[ReadOnly(new string[] { "array", "of", "strings"} )]
```

So unfortunately, you wont succeed making custom parameter type:

```
class ReadOnlyAttribute { ReadOnlyAttribute(MyClass foo) { ... } }
```

Comment: my idea is only to set true/false using the default param,eter of ReadOnly in the model. No an special parameter as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to do it within the get/set, something like:

```
class test
{
  static bool test() {
    ...
  }

  private datetime prop;

  public datetime Prop
  {
    get { return prop; }
    set
    {
      if (test)
        prop = value;
      else
        // Ignore, throw exception, etc.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not my idea, I set datetime because I am using Telerik and in this case telerik set a button calendar. For this reason I need a conditional ReadOnly, if it is true then in client-side not to be able to click in the calendar and expand it.

Answer (score 0):

[The metadata for the model (which includes your IsReadOnly)](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html) is created by the Model Metadata providers. This providers only have information about data types, and property names, but not about the concrete values of the properties of an instance of the model. So the metadata can not depend on the value of a property or method of the model class. (So implementing a Custom ModelMetada Provider wouldn't solve your problem).

Then, you have to find an alternative, hacky, way to do it:

- Create a view model with two properties, the original, without the readonly attribute and an additional readonly property, decorated with the readonly attribute.
- In the view, decide which of the two to show.

  ```
  public class MyModel
  {
      public DateTime MyProperty { get; set;}

      [ReadOnly]
      public DateTime MyPropertyRo { get; set;}
  }
  ```

If you want to recover the posted values, the editable version should use the original property in the Telerik control. The non-editable version should use the readonly property in the Telerik control, and the original property in a hidden-field, so that you can recover it in the post.

```
  @if (Model.MyPropertyIsReadOnly)
  {
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property)
     @Html.TelerikEditorFor(m => m.PropertyRo ...)
  }
  else
  {
     @Html.TelerikEditorFor(m => m.Property ...)
  }
```

If you have to do this in many different views, you can create an Html helper (extension method for Html), which receives the 3 properties and includes the last sample code.

Finally, it would be even better to make a [custom Editor template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html), but that's much harder to do if you don't have experience.

There is still another option: contact telerik, and ask them to implement a version of their control which receives a readonly parameter, and does this automatically for you. I think it must be really easy for them to implement it. So, if you're lucky enough...

Comment: When you posted it I was building your idea, I think it is the best way. I didn't know why I wanted to use the ReadOnly at the beginning. Using Razor and the model (where I set the variable), in the view I do the condition without jquery